# Same customization not working after upgrading to 5.2

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization project which using Partners site webservice to create a case. It was working perfectly ok but after I upgraded my Acumatica from version 5.10.0537 to 5.20.0531, it has stopped working. Eventually even partners site is also upgraded to same version also. It just timed out after some time.

Below is the customization code

```
        // Use webservice to create a case
        CaseAPI.Screen context = new CaseAPI.Screen();
        context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        context.Url = "https://partner.acumatica.com/Soap/SP203000.asmx";
        CaseAPI.LoginResult result = context.Login("usernam", "password***");

        CaseAPI.Content schema = context.GetSchema();
        schema.Attributes.Attribute.Commit = true;

        var commands = new CaseAPI.Command[] {
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "contract01", LinkedCommand = schema.Case.Contract},
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "Medium", LinkedCommand = schema.Case.Priority},
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "this is test sub", LinkedCommand = schema.Case.Subject },
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "this is test descrip", LinkedCommand = schema.Details.Description },

            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "Product", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Attribute},
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "Acumatica ERP", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Value, Commit = true},

            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "Product Version", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Attribute},
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "5.0", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Value, Commit = true },

            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "Version and Build Number", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Attribute},
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "8768", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Value, Commit = true },

            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "Acumatica Instance URL", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Attribute},
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "http://www.kdss.com", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Value, Commit = true },

            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "Customer Site User Name (Support)", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Attribute},
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "myname", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Value, Commit = true },

            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "Customer Site Password (Support)", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Attribute},
            new CaseAPI.Value { Value = "mypwd", LinkedCommand = schema.Attributes.Value, Commit = true },


            schema.Actions.Submit,
        };

        context.Submit(commands.ToArray());
```

The cursor just get stuck at last line of the above code. It keeps on rolling and never comes back. Finally it times out. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's difficult to help you with so little information. We don't know which version you upgraded from, what are the customizations, and what are the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: Updated the main question.

Comment: I suggest you open a support case with Acumatica, they'll troubleshoot directly with your instance.

Answer (score 0):

couple advices

1. did you update WSDL schema in your app after upgrade
2. try to simplify your code and remove for example all attributes, just leave data from the "header", will it work?